# Is there a way to pull a 404 URL from the address bar and autopopulate a form field?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, http-status-code-404, jotform

I'm encountering an issue where a user lands on a 404 page and then clicks a button to submit the 404 error they encountered. From there, they fill out a jotform (server config preventing simple form implementation from Wordpress or auxiliary plugins.)

The next step we'd like to take is to autopopulate the URL form field with the 404 error URL they encountered. Just some background info, we're operating the site through wordpress on a Windows box.

Is this possible? Seems unlikely, but I thought I'd ask and see what other developers might recommend.
(I'm aware of webmaster, analytics, and backend tracking of 404s. This was a specific setup requested for direct input from the user.)

[First time here, btw. Sorry in advance if I've broken any rules.]

Comment: It's possible, but more info is needed. What is displaying the button to submit the 404 error?

Comment: Not sure what the environment looks like, but can you use a bit of JavaScript to populate the form field from window.location.href

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can access the URL of the currently requested page via a PHP superglobal - `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

This won't always be available to you, and there may be a Wordpress helper to get it without accessing the superglobal directly - but this should get you started.

Javascript is another simple option - `window.location.href` or similar will normally give you whatever is in the address bar.